# Найти возможно-ли сделать прямоугольник

Tags: c++

Данны 3 числа.
Найти возможно-ли разделить одно так, что-бы из них сделать прямугольник где сторона это натуральное число.

Пример: 1, 5, 6: Делим 6 и получаем: 1,5,1,5

Известно что числа идут по возрастанию.

Написал следующий код, но он не проходит всех тестов.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a, b, c;
    scanf_s("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    if (a == b && c != a) {
        if (c % 2 == 0)
            cout << "YES";
        else
            cout << "NO";
        return 0;

    }
    if (c - b == a)
        cout << "YES";
    else cout << "NO";
    
}
```

Comment: На числа `2 2 2` ответ нет, когда должен быть да

Answer (score 2):

Ответ да когда выполняется любое из следующих условий:

- Есть два одинаковых числа и третье чётное
- Сумма меньших чисел равна самому большому

Comment: @Learpcs, при `2 2 6` режем 6 на две 3 и получаем прямоугольник 2*3.